# How can I multiply dates in Solidity after Safemath.sol library is deprecated

Tags: solidity

I had this piece of code compiling in Solidity 0.6.0 without errors(I'm using Remix). But suddenly SafeMath library got deprecated because it wasn't necessary to import it anymore and I don't know how to fix this line:

uint raiseUntil = now.add(durationInDays.mul(1 days));

where I calculate a future date using the ¨mul¨ function.

I let you all code below. It's the backend of a crowdfunding platform. The raisedUntil variable is the date where the deadline of the crowdfunding project ends.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0;
// Importing OpenZeppelin's SafeMath Implementation
import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';


contract Crowdfunding {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    // List of existing projects
    Project[] private projects;

    // Event that will be emitted whenever a new project is started
    event ProjectStarted(
        address contractAddress,
        address projectStarter,
        string projectTitle,
        string projectDesc,
        uint256 deadline,
        uint256 goalAmount
    );

    /** @dev Function to start a new project.
      * @param title Title of the project to be created
      * @param description Brief description about the project
      * @param durationInDays Project deadline in days
      * @param amountToRaise Project goal in wei
      */
    function startProject(
        string calldata title,
        string calldata description,
        uint durationInDays,
        uint amountToRaise
    ) external {
        uint raiseUntil = now.add(durationInDays.mul(1 days));
        Project newProject = new Project(msg.sender, title, description, raiseUntil, amountToRaise);
        projects.push(newProject);
        emit ProjectStarted(
            address(newProject),
            msg.sender,
            title,
            description,
            raiseUntil,
            amountToRaise
        );
    }                                                                                                                                   

    /** @dev Function to get all projects' contract addresses.
      * @return A list of all projects' contract addreses
      */
    function returnAllProjects() external view returns(Project[] memory){
        return projects;
    }
}


contract Project {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    
    // Data structures
    enum State {
        Fundraising,
        Expired,
        Successful
    }

    // State variables
    address payable public creator;
    uint public amountGoal; // required to reach at least this much, else everyone gets refund
    uint public completeAt;
    uint256 public currentBalance;
    uint public raiseBy;
    string public title;
    string public description;
    State public state = State.Fundraising; // initialize on create
    mapping (address => uint) public contributions;

    // Event that will be emitted whenever funding will be received
    event FundingReceived(address contributor, uint amount, uint currentTotal);
    // Event that will be emitted whenever the project starter has received the funds
    event CreatorPaid(address recipient);

    // Modifier to check current state
    modifier inState(State _state) {
        require(state == _state);
        _;
    }

    // Modifier to check if the function caller is the project creator
    modifier isCreator() {
        require(msg.sender == creator);
        _;
    }

    constructor
    (
        address payable projectStarter,
        string memory projectTitle,
        string memory projectDesc,
        uint fundRaisingDeadline,
        uint goalAmount
    ) public {
        creator = projectStarter;
        title = projectTitle;
        description = projectDesc;
        amountGoal = goalAmount;
        raiseBy = fundRaisingDeadline;
        currentBalance = 0;
    }

    /** @dev Function to fund a certain project.
      */
    function contribute() external inState(State.Fundraising) payable {
        require(msg.sender != creator);
        contributions[msg.sender] = contributions[msg.sender].add(msg.value);
        currentBalance = currentBalance.add(msg.value);
        emit FundingReceived(msg.sender, msg.value, currentBalance);
        checkIfFundingCompleteOrExpired();
    }

    /** @dev Function to change the project state depending on conditions.
      */
    function checkIfFundingCompleteOrExpired() public {
        if (currentBalance >= amountGoal) {
            state = State.Successful;
            payOut();
        } else if (now > raiseBy)  {
            state = State.Expired;
        }
        completeAt = now;
    }

    /** @dev Function to give the received funds to project starter.
      */
    function payOut() internal inState(State.Successful) returns (bool) {
        uint256 totalRaised = currentBalance;
        currentBalance = 0;

        if (creator.send(totalRaised)) {
            emit CreatorPaid(creator);
            return true;
        } else {
            currentBalance = totalRaised;
            state = State.Successful;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /** @dev Function to retrieve donated amount when a project expires.
      */
    function getRefund() public inState(State.Expired) returns (bool) {
        require(contributions[msg.sender] > 0);

        uint amountToRefund = contributions[msg.sender];
        contributions[msg.sender] = 0;

        if (!msg.sender.send(amountToRefund)) {
            contributions[msg.sender] = amountToRefund;
            return false;
        } else {
            currentBalance = currentBalance.sub(amountToRefund);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /** @dev Function to get specific information about the project.
      * @return Returns all the project's details
      */
    function getDetails() public view returns 
    (
        address payable projectStarter,
        string memory projectTitle,
        string memory projectDesc,
        uint256 deadline,
        State currentState,
        uint256 currentAmount,
        uint256 goalAmount
    ) {
        projectStarter = creator;
        projectTitle = title;
        projectDesc = description;
        deadline = raiseBy;
        currentState = state;
        currentAmount = currentBalance;
        goalAmount = amountGoal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might decide to switch to a newer version of Solidity (current is 0.8.4), where `now` is [deprecated](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/070-breaking-changes.html#changes-to-the-syntax) so I already used `block.timestamp` instead. It's the same thing - `now` was just its alias.

The SafeMath library checks whether an arithmetic operation (such as multiplication or addition) on two unsigned integers would overflow/underflow. If it would, it throws an exception. If it wouldn't, it performs the arithmetic operation. Since Solidity 0.8 this is done automatically and SafeMath is not needed, so another reason to use the current version.

---

In Solidity 0.8 and newer, if this would overflow, it would throw an exception automatically

```
uint raiseUntil = block.timestamp + durationInDays * 1 days;
```

---

In older versions, you'll need to check for the possible overflow yourself and throw the exception from your code (the same behavior as SafeMath would do).

```
uint durationInSeconds = durationInDays * 1 days;

// Check that the result of division (inverse operation to multiplication) is the original number.
// If it's not, throw an exception, because the multiplication overflowed.
require(durationInSeconds / durationInDays == 1 days, 'Multiplication overflow');

uint raiseUntil = block.timestamp + durationInSeconds;

// Check that the result of subtraction (inverse operation to addition) is the original number.
// If it's not, throw an exception, because the addition overflowed.
require(raiseUntil - block.timestamp == durationInSeconds, 'Addition overflow');
```

---

[Integer overflow/underflow](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-101) is one of the most common security vulnerabilities in smart contracts. If your `startProject()` function was vulnerable, it would only allow to start a project with a deadline in the past. But in other implementations it can have more serious consequences. For example if an attacker exploits this vulnerability on a token contract, it could allow them to spend more tokens than they own.